# Batch to exe delete itself

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I compiled my batch file to exe with 3rd party program. But when i compile it, my `delete it self` line not working. How can I fix it?

```
start /b "" cmd /c del "%~f0"&exit /b
```

Comment: The recommended self delete method is your last line to read `(GoTo) 2>Nul & Del "%~f0"`. That said, because you've wrapped your script inside a self-extracting executable, it should extract the contained file _(s)_ to a 'hidden' directory and run prior to the extracted file _(s)_ being deleted. There should be no need to self delete the script for that reason.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you wrote, my bad English. There is any way to delete itself after execution? `(GoTo) 2>Nul & Del "%~f0"` didn't worked when I compile.

Comment: I made it clear that once the wrapper has extracted and run the script it will delete it anyway, you do not need to add a self delete command!

Comment: The meta variable %0 is the batch file. It is Not the executable wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set dt=%date%
echo %dt% - is todays date
echo MsgBox "%dt% - is todays date">out.vbs
out.vbs
del out.vbs
goto quit
:quit
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
exit
```

---

### **Save the above as batch (*.bat)**

**del "%~f0"** command will only delete the batch itself and not the compiled **(*.exe)** executable.

The compiled executable is just a container which extracts the actual batch to a temporary location then runs it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your batch a temporary secondary process which will delete your primary one after a short delay provided by ping:

```
echo ping localhost > %TEMP%\secondary.cmd
echo del FullPathTo\CompiledBatch.exe >> %TEMP%\secondary.cmd
echo exit >> %TEMP%\secondary.cmd
start /b "" %TEMP%\secondary.cmd
exit
```